# How can i deploy multiple spring boot services in gcp app engine?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am working with dialogflow and i have two spring boot projects, one is a rest api and another is the webhook for fullfilment.

My projects structure is like below:

```
chatbot-services (regular directory)
    | 
    └─── chatbot-webhook (springboot project)
    |      └─ src
    |          └─ main
    |              └─ appengine
    |              |      └─ app.yaml         
    |              └─ java
    |              └─ resources
    |                     
    └─── api-service (springboot project)
          └─ src
              └─ main
                  └─ appengine
                  |      └─ app.yaml         
                  └─ java
                  └─ resources
```

I am trying to deploy both from chatbot-services, like this:

```
gcloud app deploy chatbot-webhook api-service
```

but it shows me this output:

[image]

I already tried to delete the files in conflict but all the files collide.

I also tried to deploy it like this:

```
gcloud app deploy chatbot-webhook/src/main/appengine/app.yaml api-service/src/main/appengine/app.yaml
```

and it shows me this error:
[image]

How can i deploy multiple services to app engine? i would appreciate any help

Comment: Can you share the content of the app.yaml files? And did this work when you deploy only 1 service at a time?

Comment: in additon to @guillaumeblaquiere comment, did you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files) on how to structure your services in app engine?

Comment: probably you need to give two different service names in the app.yaml files.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy using the version name separately.

For example, you can deploy the two projects using using

`gcloud app deploy --version="chatbot-webhook"`

`gcloud app deploy --version="api-service"`

However, there might be only one version that receives traffics from your project website, so add

`--no-promote`
option to the one you don't want to have traffics to.